# How to get the recent 10 users by date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table named users with columns username and created_date. I want to get 10 recently created users by using query.

Query:

```
select to_char(created_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  from users
 order by created_date desc;
```

This returns users created in descending order. But I want to get first 10 records.

Comment: What did you try? SO is not homework site.

Comment: select * from users order by created_date desc.. do a ajax request to the server using jquery $.post or $.get ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use subquery and ROWNUM
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY created_date DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10`

Answer (score 0):

Append to your query:

```
limit 10
```

so you get only the first 10 results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select username,to_char(created_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
from user where (username,created_date) in 
(select username,created_date from user order by 
created_date desc) and rownum <=10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
);
```